# What's the prize for getting all the Eddy River coins?

Tags: paper-mario-the-origami-king

After I finished the Eddy River rapids the Toad rowing my boat told me I could have gotten a prize if I had gotten a the coins. To be honest, I hated that section and am unlikely to do it again, but I am curious what I missed out on. What's the prize for getting all the coins while going down the Eddy River rapids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a Coin Collector Trophy that goes in the Museé Champignon! There are 15 Trophies in the game. They are different than collectibles, so if you’re a completionist, you’ll wanna complete the Eddy River challenge! Good luck!

Comment: I loved that section, but it’s horrible that you can’t manually retry. Missed a coin? Too bad: complete the course anyway, and then LATER you get to try again from the start.